# Quarkus ExceptionMapper is not triggered

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I'm trying to customise the response for authentication failures in Quarkus. I need to set a custom header, a custom response code and a custom response body. I developed my custom (Kotlin) `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` because I need a custom authentication logic. In it, I tried returning a failure Uni.

```
return Uni.createFrom().failure(AuthenticationFailedException())
```

And then implement my own `ExceptionMapper`

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
class AuthenticationFailedExceptionMapper : ExceptionMapper<AuthenticationFailedException> {

    override fun toResponse(exception: AuthenticationFailedException): Response {
        logger.info("====== custom auth error")
```

It doesn't get triggered. I have proactive authentication disabled:

```
quarkus.http.auth.proactive=false
```

Instead, I noticed that the `getChallenge` method in my custom `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` gets triggered, which can be used to overwrite the response, but it doesn't allow to set the body, just the result code and one header.

I also tried returning and mapping a different, custom exception, but then I only see some errors in the log and the client gets a 500 response code - the exception mapper is still not triggered. Why?

Comment: Can you add the dependencies of your `pom.xml` as well?